# GeoServer Repeat rendering (EPSG:4326)

Tags: gis, geoserver

I try to make .dwg to .shp with Arcgis for autocad and Qgis

I define the coordinate system as EPSG:4326. like：
[image]

and display fine on the Qgis:

[image]

But use GeoServer, Repeat rendering ：

[image]
 The coordinate system I set:

[image]

But when I set the SRS to EPSG:3857,It work fine!
[image]

what happened? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not in 4326.

With this projection (4326), the bounds are +- 180 and +- 90 degrees. Your first screenshot and the Geoserver one show coordinates with values around 73000.

--> the data source has the wrong coordinate.
--> QGIS manage to display it
--> Geoserver fails at this

You need to fix the coordinate system at the source

Comment: thanks!you're right.The data not in 4326.But I don't know how to convert dwg file Correctly.